# Fragment Transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I have a ListFragment with a floating action button. When the button is clicked, i want to replace the ListFragment with a CreateListFragment. Instead, the CreateListFragment is placed on top of the  ListFragment and the button and textview from the  ListFragment are still visible. I am not sure what went wrong. How do I completely replace the ListFragment with the CreateListFragment?

Here is the screenshot before the button is clicked
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2HxP.png

Here is a screenshot after the button is clicked
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYN47.png

list_fragment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listFrame">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:src="@drawable/create"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEmpty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="No Shopping Lists Yet"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>


</FrameLayout>``
```

createlist_fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:padding="10dp"
         tools:context="com.lavineoluoch.helloworld.swiftpay.app.CreateListFragment">
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etListTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/title"/>
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etAddItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/items"/>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEditItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btnEdit"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            />
</RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

ListFragment.java

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           CreateListFragment createListFragment = new CreateListFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listFrame,createListFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Try fab.hide(); on click of that

Comment: I had already tried that, didn't work. But thanks for your suggestion. The answer below worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your root view for your Fragments insert this line of code:

```
android:background="?android:windowBackground"
```

As you have a see through background your view can still see the reminiscence of the replaced Fragment as the view hasn't yet updated.

The above answer should solve your problem, however I would recommend re-structuring your approach and instead launching a new Activity which contains the CreateListFragment when the FAB is pressed. Doing so would result in easier to maintain code which is also easier to read and would be best practice. It would also mean that the user can press their back button and navigate back to ListActivity/ListFragment without you needing to manually handle Fragment back stacks.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and suggestion. I will definitely consider changing my approach. However, I chose to use fragments because I have a navigation drawer i would like to appear on each activity. So I thought I would use one activity with the NavigationView and fragments within the main content. Is there a better way I could achieve my goal?

Comment: You can still use a `NavigationDrawer`. Make a base `Activity` for all activities which use a `NavigationDrawer` and put all of your drawer logic inside there. Then extend from your new drawer class in both `CreateListActivity` and `ListActivity`. Using this approach would also mean you can change the content of your drawer if need be depending on the `Activity` which is extending from it.